# Realm updating/adding when location changes

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to save location data in Realm, and I want it to be saved as new data but under the same name when the location changes.

Below is saving the last location but I want it to be every location

**Realm Class**

```
@objc dynamic var latitude = CLLocationDegrees()
@objc dynamic var longitude = CLLocationDegrees()
```

**ViewController Class**

```
var myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
var lat = CLLocationDegrees()
var lon = CLLocationDegrees()
let data = Data()
```

*didUpdateLocations*

```
let theLocation = locations[0]
myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theLocation.coordinate.latitude, theLocation.coordinate.longitude)
saveData()
```

*saveData function*

```
func saveData() {
  do {
     let realm = try Realm()
     try realm.write {
         data.latitude = myLocation.latitude
         data.longitude = myLocation.longitude
         realm.add(data)
     }
   } catch {
     print("Error: \(error)"
   }
}
```

I don't know if I'm calling `saveData()` in the wrong place, or by doing `realm.add(data)` it's replacing the data that was there with the new lat/long data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's 1 instance here

```
let data = Data()
```

You need

```
func saveData() {
  do {
     let realm = try Realm()
     let data = Data()
     try realm.write {
         data.latitude = myLocation.latitude
         data.longitude = myLocation.longitude
         realm.add(data)
     }
   } catch {
     print("Error: \(error)"
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! Been confused for hours trying to figure that out!